# Do there exist infinitely many primes in the form $x^3 -1$?

Tags: proof-writing, problem-solving

The number $7$ is of the form $x^3 − 1$, where $x = 2$. Do there exist infinitely many prime numbers of the form $x^3 − 1$?

Comment: if you do not restrict $x$ to be integers then every prime number can be expressed in $x^3-1$, where $x$ is real

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ and so…

Comment: I actually already had this hint, but I'm not sure how this proves the question

Comment: Wizard- what's the definition of a prime number?

Comment: @Wizard Suppose $x>2$; then $x-1\ge2$ and so…